# 404 - File or directory not found with Azure/GoDaddy

Tags: cname-record, azure, godaddy

I'm moving my web host from GoDaddy to Azure, and I'm getting the error above.

These are the steps I followed:

1) Made my azure website the paid (yet shared) version

2) Went to GoDaddy and changed A record to @ 168.62.224.13 (shared server ip)

3) Under CNAME entered "www" in the CNAME column, and "mysite.azurewebsites.net" in the 'points to' column.

www.mysite.com goes to the IP, but it does not find my site so I get the 404.  Did I neglect to do something?

I did confirm the CNAME is mysite.azurewebsites.net at mxtoolbox.com.

**Solution:**  There is a step 4.  In Azure under Manage Custom Domains I needed to add my www.mysite.com.  Worked instantly.

Comment: If I go to http://168.62.224.13 it fails, this does not look like a DNS issue, are you sure the website is running on the Azure server? Try logging in via Remote Desktop and see if you can open the site locally (http://localhost)

Comment: Azure under "Manage custom domains" says "The IP address to use when you configure A records 168.62.224.13".  This is shared hosting so I think the problem is that it needs to correctly route to my shared location on the server.  Not sure if Remote Desktop works with shared hosting.

Comment: @David - please post your solution as an *answer*, and not as an edit to the original question. This way, people can vote on the answer, and an *accepted answer* can be marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple oversight.  The instructions were not clear, but there is a step 4. In Azure under Manage Custom Domains I needed to add my www.mysite.com. Worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that you need to add all of the CNAME redirects chained to your Azure redirection, that are being used by your users.

Example: Domain A redirects to B which redirects to C which redirects to Azue.

A -> B -> C -> Azure

Adding only domain B to Manage Custom Domains will cause 404 while redirecting from A and C. You need to add all of them to the console.